# npm install deployd –g issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need to setup the web server for Angular.js application using Nodejs. Accordingly I installed node.js version 6.11.0 in the path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Next step is to install module of nodejs using the command:

```
npm install deployd -g
```

I am installing it in a path where my node_modules are installed.

When I run the command: `npm install deployd –g` I get one warning message (please see image for reference)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AWQE.png)

So I get to know that deployd is installed in the path `C:\Program\node_modules\deployd`.

Now if I run `dpd –V command`, it shows that dpd is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Can anybody please help me installing deployd?

Comment: have you followed the troubleshooting steps for deployd?  http://docs.deployd.com/docs/getting-started/installing-deployd.html#s-Troubleshooting-747

Comment: yes..but i didn't worked for me @claies

Comment: `C:\Progam` isn't the same as `C:\Program Files`;  I'm not really even sure it's recommended to use the path `C:\Program` for anything in Windows.....

Comment: @Claies, it is the default directory where deployd installed.
I even change the path and tried installing in some other folder: G:\MVC_STUDY_MATERIAL\Angular Js\angular js new\node_modules and i could able to download connect module of node js but i am not able to install deployd module of it. Can you please help me out with this

Comment: what shell are you using there?  `cmd.exe`, `cmd.exe (as admin)`, `git-bash.exe`, `powershell.exe`, etc. all set their own paths;  maybe the path in your shell isn't seeing the install directory?

Comment: @Claies cmd.exe as admin and i have chosen the path: G:\MVC_STUDY_MATERIAL\Angular Js\angular js new\node_modules

Comment: that would be the location for local modules, but not for global modules using -g.....

Comment: @Claies my global path is C:\Program\node_modules but when i try to run the command dpd -V it shows dpd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @Claies i installed deployd in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployd and added the path variable as well, But still it doesn't work. If you have time then we can communicate personally as it is very important for me to proceed with my work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help. It's worked for me.

```
npm install deployd-cli -g
```